# I cant get/access the value of my session variables to another page

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Im having a problem of accessing the session variable value.

im creating a login page and this were i set the values of my session variables.

**index.php**

```
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        session_regenerate_id();
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_ID'] = $user['id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_UNAME'] = $user['username'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_PASS'] = $user['password'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location:home.php");
        exit();
    }
```

**home.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_ID'])) == ''){
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
<body>
    <p>Login Successful</p>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem here is i have no value in $_SESSION['SESS_ID']..so how do i get or access the value of this session variable in my home.php?

Comment: do you have `session_start();` on the `index.php`?

Comment: @bansi yes i do have a session_start in my index.php

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` line.

The reason your session is not getting set is because with the call to `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` the internal data pointer of `$result` has advanced and your `$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` does not have the values you expect which is why all the session variables you are setting are empty.

Answer (score 1):

**index.php**

```
session_start();
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        session_regenerate_id();
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_ID'] = $user['id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_UNAME'] = $user['username'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_PASS'] = $user['password'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location:home.php");
        exit();
    }
```

Add `session_start()` on the index.php

Answer (score 1):

The only problem that causes such result, when Session variables have stored no data. your code is write. Please check your index.php for session_start(): on the top.